# Trying to output a list of values from excel spreadsheet but the values keep overiding each other rather than compiling in the output spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have included the code below for a python script that retrieves a certain cell value from multiple excel files in a Root directory. Then it is supposed to output these values in a list in the outputted excel file called Test.xls. The problem that I am having is that each time the script runs through a new excel file and calculates a value it replaces the value it had calculated before. This leaves me with an outputted excel spreadsheet that only contains the single value of the last excel spreadsheet it calculated.

```
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd

index = 0

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
Testsheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
print("Provide row")
row = int(input())
print("Provide column")
col = int(input())
path= 'U:/SWEModelConstruction/Milk'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xls') ]
for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
     wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
     n = len(wb.sheets())
for s in range(n) :
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(s)
    data=sheet.cell(row,col).value
    Testsheet.write(index, 0, data)
index=index+1

workbook.save('Test.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for row and col input at the start of your code; however, note that in your final for loop the row and col values are not incremented. So every new calculated value will be written / overwritten in the same cell of the output excel sheet. Overwriting would leave final data in the cell equal to the last calculation:
    for s in range(n) :
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(s)
        data=sheet.cell(row,col).value
        Testsheet.write(index, 0, data)
Also, just a side comment not related, but the increment of index at the end appears to be unnecessary and could be deleted.

Comment: Your code not presented correctly. Put new line separating code and text.

Answer (score 0):

index = index + 1 is not indented, so its not part of the for loop

Comment: even when I indent it it still does not fix my issue